# Ubuntu misindentifies external monitor - how do create a new monitor definition with a correctly sized viewport?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm connecting an RCA 22" class LED full HDTV, model number DETG215R via HDMI. Ubuntu Display identifies it as an Avolites Ltd 23". It wouldn't bother me except that Ubuntu thinks the monitor is bigger than it is, so the controls for a maximized window are just slightly out of reach.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this? Or how to create a new monitor definition with a correctly sized viewport? Thanks!

Comment: Some HDTVs have controls to tweak the display size.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - It's called overscan.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set it in some GUI app but I'm not sure about the level of customization or using a command-line tool xrandr:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/xrandr.1.html
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution